# Method has interface type as parameter, but doesn't take objects which implement this interface?

Tags: java

In short, I have a method which takes a list of an interface, but when I provide such a list via generic constraint `<C extends FooInterface>`, it doesn't work:

```
public class Utils {
    public void testMethod(List<FooInterface> list){}
}

public class TestClass<C extends FooInterface> {
    public final List<C> lists;
    public TestClass(){
        Utils.testMethod(lists); //<< this does not work because "C" is not "FooInterface"
    }
}
```

I think this should work as I defined `C` as `implements FooInterface`.

Comment: is FooInterface class or interface? If interface it should C implements FooInterface.

Comment: It's poker night, 'cos you're going to learn about [wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

Comment: This is perfectly normal.  It's probably simplest to change `testMethod` to accept a `List<? extends FooInterface>`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman this also does not work: Required typ as ? extends FooInterface, but provided is "List<C>"

Comment: Post your complete code as a new question.

Comment: the provided answer which flags my question as duplicate answered my question. Its just not possible.

Comment: This is almost certainly a solvable problem, depending on what exactly `testMethod` does.